# pascal case property names and Spring JPA Repository method name

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that has mixed camel and pascal case properties that I can't change:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
   public int id;
   public String camelCaseProp;
   public double GenerationEnergy;
   [...]
}
```

when I have a method like

```
MyEntity findTop1ByGenerationEnergy(double generationEnergy);
```

it says that there is no property `generationEnergy` - "did you mean `GenerationEnergy`?"

Is there a way to keep using those methods without `@Query` annotation and use them with my PascalCase properties along with my camelCase ones?

Thanks!

Comment: Does Spring determine the field name from method- not from parameter name? So `findTop1ByGenerationEnergy(double GenerationEnergy);` will not work?

Comment: it determines the field name from method name - I tried what you suggested 
 and I am getting the same error

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: have your getters and setters proper names? If so you might be able to set AccessType to use those.

Comment: in my case I am not using getters and setters.. all entities are having public properties since they are not real classes and dont have any business logic.. as such I dont use getters and setters for those.. could you elaborate a bit more?